# Counting "Digram" aka pairs of nucleotides in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, count, fasta

I need to write a function that takes a fasta file and counts the digrams (AT, CG, TT, CC, etc) in the file.

My for loop currently reads the file line by line, and produces the count for that line. Then it restarts the count in the next line. (This is all organized into a dictionary)

I want to maintain the counts each line, so I get a count for the whole file, not just individual lines.

This is my code that I'm trying to fix:

```
dinucleotides = ['AA','AT','AG','AC',
                 'TA','TT','TG','TC',
                 'GA','GT','GG','GC',
                 'CA','CT','CG','CT']

all_counts = {}

with open('short.fasta', 'r') as dna_file:
    dna_file.readline()

    for line in dna_file:
        my_line = line.strip()

        for pairs in dinucleotides:
            count = my_line.count(pairs)
            all_counts[pairs] = count
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with `int` as a `default_factory`.
And change `all_counts[pairs] = count` to `all_counts[pairs] += count`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


dinucleotides = ['AA','AT','AG','AC',
                 'TA','TT','TG','TC',
                 'GA','GT','GG','GC',
                 'CA','CT','CG','CT']

all_counts = defaultdict(int)

with open('short.fasta', 'r') as dna_file:
    dna_file.readline()

    for line in dna_file:
        my_line = line.strip()

        for pairs in dinucleotides:
            count = my_line.count(pairs)
            all_counts[pairs] += count
```

Or, use `dict.setdefault` method.

```py
...
all_counts = {}
...
            all_counts.setdefault(pairs, 0) += count
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the last count you had,

```
all_counts[pairs] = all_counts.get(pairs, 0) + count
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to initialize a Python dict mapping each 2gram to zero, and increment that according to each line. Here, I will assume that the FASQ file only contains bases in "ATGC". In addition, iterating over each possible pair for each line requires 16 passes over each line. This can be avoided by passing each line once with look-ahead and saving each pair. Perhaps as follows:

```
import random

def random_dnukes(lines=1000, cols=40):
  return [''.join(random.choices('ATGC', k=cols)) for _ in range(lines)]

# e.g.
# ['TGACTCGTCAAAGGTACGTTAATCCTTGGGCAGTTACGGG',
#  'ATTGTTCAATCGAACGTTCGCTACTCGACTCGCGCCCCCT',
#  'TCCCGTGGGACAGGTTCCCAATTGACCGGACGCCGGACTC',
#  'TCGTCGTGCCCCGACATTGCTTCACGGCGGTGCGCGCTGG',
#  'GGTCCGGTCTAGGCGATCCCTAATAGTCAAGCACCGATTA',
#  'CCGAGCCTTGTGTATACTCTGTAAACACTTCTTCCCATAC',
#  'CGGATAGCAGCTAGTGGTTCCCGCAGTACAGGATGACCAA',
#  'CTCGGACGAGAAATCAGGCCAACCTCCACTGGCGACAGAA',
#  'TCTGACCTGCAGTGCAGTCCAGTTATAGTGGAACACCAGC',
#  'GTCAGCCCTTATCCGTTAGCCCAGGTGCCTCAATAGGAGG']

fake_file_iterator = iter(random_dnukes(1000, 40))

from collections import defaultdict
total_counts = defaultdict(int)

for line in fake_file_iterator:
  line = line.strip()
  for i in range(len(line) - 1):
    total_counts[line[i:i+2]] += 1

for k, v in total_counts.items():
  print(k, v)
```

Resulting in

```
GC 2497
CC 2382
CG 2444
GT 2422
TT 2508
TA 2373
AC 2466
GG 2408
TG 2473
CA 2462
AA 2412
CT 2448
AG 2454
GA 2470
TC 2400
AT 2381
```